# Computing dot product of sparse vectors in less than O(n+m) complexity, where m and n are the number of non zero entries in the respective vectors

Tags: algorithm

Given an operation memset(array of values, array of memory location) which stores the corresponding values in the corresponding memory locations and takes O(1) time irrespective of the length of the array. How do you use it to calculate the dot product of sparse vectors in less than O(n+m) complexity? Each vector is represented as a triplet of [val,index,len], where len is the number of non zero entries, index is an array of indexes of non zero entries, and val is an array consisting of the non zero entries, so size of val=size of index=len.
Assume the array index is sorted.

Comment: What does m stand for? Isn't the complexity of the dot product of two vectors O(n) since the vectors need to be the same length?

Comment: How are these "sparse vectors" represented?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of my problem statement. I have edited it to address your specific concerns.

Comment: How can you expect to run faster than the size of the input?

Comment: Maybe because we have an operation which runs faster than the size of the input

Comment: An adversarial argument shows that you must consume all the input.

Comment: What if rather than taking O(1) time the memset operation took one clock cycle, that is we could replace operations like if/for that take more than one clock cycle with the memset operation. Can we get a more efficient implementation then? And by eficient I dont mean it should be less than O(n+m), just less number of operations in one run of the algorithm.